# Sharepoint 2007 features are not available

Tags: installation, central-administration

I have installed sharepoint 2007 and configured. After finishing that. I am not able to get some of the features in central admin

to name few
under central admin--> operation 
     1. Content and deployment
     2. Upgrade and Migration
under central administration --> Application management
     1.Reporting Services
     2.Search
     3.Office Sharepoint Server Shared Service
     4. Info path forms service

note: Office SharePoint Server Search service is missing
can anybody help me to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Did you by any chance install WSS3 rather than MOSS2007? WSS3 does not have the more advanced features provided by MOSS.

Comment: Smart idea! +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all your services are started. 
Then create an SSP, a shared service provider. This will host your search service and other things like mysite.

Make sure you have a good whitepapier with you that guides you through the installation.

If you need more specific help, please provide some additional information about your farm environment, your setup and what steps you have completed already.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled the features at the web application level?  Application Management -> Manage Web Application Features.